# Invariant Violation error when returning a Link as dataFormatter in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

In the table Column title I want to return links which navigate to edit mode of each of these titles. I'm using react-bootstrap-table and I created a custom data formatter in the constructor of my component

```
class Grid extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.anchorFormatter = (cell, row, slug) => {
      let link = "/"+slug;
      return (
        <Link to={link}>
          {cell}
        </Link>
      )
  }
```

I then call this data formatted in the table

```
<TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField="title" dataSort dataFormat={ this.anchorFormatter }>Title</TableHeaderColumn>
```

This is get this error

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `TableBody`.
```

The second part is how do I pass value of slug to the data formatter? I get data like this from the get request API Call

```
{
  "title": "Experiments in DataOps",
  "status": true,
  "publish_date": "2020-01-29",
  "slug": "experiments-in-dataops"
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach is to create a class or function and then use it as a component, here I create the component

```
class BlogAnchor extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Link to={this.props.link}>&nbsp;{this.props.linkText}&nbsp;</Link>
        );
    }
}
```

then in the Grid class I have a function

```
anchorFormatter(cell, row) {
    let link = "blogs/" + row.slug;
    return <BlogAnchor link={link} linkText={cell} />;
}
```

which is also registered in the constructor of Grid class

```
this.anchorFormatter = this.anchorFormatter.bind(this);
```

And the table column refers to this this function

```
<TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField="title" dataSort dataFormat {this.anchorFormatter}>Title</TableHeaderColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use raw html tags instead of link for this to work, i.e.

```
const anchorFormat = (cell,row) => {
  let link = '#/blogs/' + row.slug;
  return ( <div><a className="nav-link" href={link}>{cell}</a></div>);
}
```